# insufficient access rights on object id

Tags: api, wsdl

I'm facing an issue using **`soap api`**. I try to delete duplicate rules by using partner WSDL soap. But I got that error when tried to perform delete operation.
Error is that :

> "insufficient access rights on object id"

I'm using system admin user credentials for access api.
If anyone have any idea about that most welcome.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet?